Tax implications for non-citizen of transferring encashed equity to the U.S. while temporarily abroad
I am an Indian citizen and have been working in the U.S. on H1B visa for a few years. My visa is set to expire at the end of this year, which may necessitate a temporary return to India before I find another employment in the U.S.
During my time in India, I plan to cash in equity from a startup based in Singapore. This equity was granted to me many years ago, prior to my arrival in the U.S. I never cashed in the equity while residing in the U.S. on an H1B visa, as I understood that doing so would have required me to pay taxes on the capital gains.
If I leave the U.S. for several months, intending to return mid-next year on a new visa, I plan to maintain my U.S. bank account during this period.
Given this scenario, where I am neither residing nor working in the U.S. during the initial part of 2025, I’d like to understand the tax implications. Specifically, if I transfer funds from the encashed equity in Singapore to my U.S. bank account, would this be subject to U.S. taxes, even though I am not a resident or employed in the U.S. at the time of the transaction?
Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

How's this question different from your previous question?

You pass the Substantial Presence Test for 2025 (and are thus a resident alien for 2025) if you are present in the US for 31 days in 2025, and (days of presence in 2025 + 1/3 days of presence in 2024 + 1/6 days of presence in 2023) >= 183 days. If you were present for almost all of 2023 and 2024, then you pretty much meet the 183 days (1/3  + 1/6 = 1/2), so if you are present in the US for 31 days in 2025, you will be a resident alien for all of 2025, unless you are present for less than 183 days in 2025, and manage to claim the "Closer Connection to a Foreign Country" exception.

@user102008 all that is not very relevant. Based on the OP's previous questions and responses, the taxable event has already occured. The OP thinks that the US taxes the money when it is transferred, but that's not true - the tax is due when the income is earned (i.e.: stocks have vested, and stocks have been sold, not proceeds transferred)

@littleadv: The OP says they "plan to cash in equity" while in India in 2025. I interpret "cash in equity" to mean selling the stock.
